# QueryDsl 5 with Mapstruct issues while generating resources

Tags: spring-boot, maven, querydsl, mapstruct

I am trying to use MapStruct alongside with QueryDsl,Spring Boot 3 and Java 17 but it seems like the `maven-compiler-plugin` I use for MapStruct prevents QueryDsl resources from being generated.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I remove `maven-compiler-plugin` QueryDsl resources are getting generated but MapStruct's not.

I have also tried to add QueryDsl annotation processors without any luck.

```
<path>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</path>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: remove `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration, add `mapstruct-processor` as dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: sadly mapstruct beans are not getting injected now. Both mapstruct and querydsl resources seems to be inplace tho.

Comment: In general you have two options: either take advantage of annotation processor discover in javac (define all jars with annotation processors as dependencies with scope=provided) or setup full set of annotation processors in `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration (i.e. you need to add `querydsl-apt` to `annotationProcessorPaths`). Both options should lead to the same result

Comment: I have done both and none of them works as expected. It's probably a bug with QueryDsl 5.0.0

Comment: Hi @ThanosM did you solve your issues? I am running in an the same issue

Comment: Sadly I didn't manage to resolve my issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by other comments one solution is to completely remove maven-compiler-plugin and add the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will generate both mapstruct and querydsl resources.

To force mapstruct generate the mappers as Spring beans I also had to set
`componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING` attribute in @Mapper annotation.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove maven-compiler-plugin and leave only these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```